# spark dataframe add a new column with a function returning a string

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame with a date column in string.

[image]

I would like to add a new column with one day added into column date and it should look like this.

[image]

Now I create a list, build up a sequence with a function strDateAdd made by myself before I convert it into a dataframe and join it with the original one, which seems troublesome. Any other neater way of doing this?

```
  val lisBABDate=dtfMIDD_CONS_AAAA.select("BAB","Date").collect.map(x => (x(0).toString,x(1).toString)).toList

  var seqBABDate=Seq(("000","000","000"))

  lisBABDate.foreach((e=> {
    val (strBAB, strDate) = e
    seqBABDate = (strBAB,strDate,strDateAdd(strDate,1))+: seqBABDate
  }))

  val dtfBABDate1=seqBABDate.toDF("BAB","Date","Date1")

  val dtf2=dtf1.join(dtfBABDate1,Seq("BAB","Date"),"inner")
```

Comment: can you please check and let us know if the solution below works - appreciate if you can approve and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work. I still need the date column in string format 'yyyymmdd'

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, row_number}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("A", "20200501"),
  ("B", "20211121"),
  ("C", "20151230")
)).toDF("BAI", "Date")

df.withColumn("AAB", to_date(col("Date"),"yyyyMMdd")).
withColumn("AAC", date_add ($"AAB", 1)).
  withColumn("AAD", $"AAC".cast(DataTypes.StringType)).
  withColumn("Date1",regexp_replace($"AAD",lit("-"),lit("")))
```

Answer (score 0):

use **selectExpr()** along with **`date_add()`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A","20120201"),("B","20210430"),("A","20160608"),("A","20201120")],["id","date"])
df = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.col("date"),"yyyyMMdd"))
df = df.selectExpr('*', 'date_add(date, 1) as next_date')
df.show()

+---+----------+----------+
| id|      date| next_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|  A|2012-02-01|2012-02-02|
|  B|2021-04-30|2021-05-01|
|  A|2016-06-08|2016-06-09|
|  A|2020-11-20|2020-11-21|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd line did not go through